# Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined, parameters are mapped?

Tags: php

Pretty sure I mapped the parameters right but still getting this error.  I've tried matching up the parameters with the query and they match fine.  I've also tried several other things but nothing is solving the issue.  Any ideas?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE stores SET Name = :Name, Legal_Entity__c = :Legal_Entity__c, Opening_Date__c = :Opening_Date__c, Owner_Type__c = :Owner_Type__c, Yumtracker_Status__c = :Yumtracker_Status__c, Hypercare_Status__c = :Hypercare_Status__c,BOH_Type__c = :BOH_Type__c,Store_Type__c = :Store_Type__c,Address_Line_1__c = :Address_Line_1__c,Address_Line_2__c = :Address_Line_2__c,City__c = :City__c,State__c = :State__c,Zip__c = :Zip__c,Store_Email_Address__c = :Store_Email_Address__c,Time_Zone__c = :Time_Zone__c,Area_Coach__c = :Area_Coach__c,RGM__c = :RGM__c,RTO_Date__c = :RTO_Date__c,Ground_Break_Date__c = :Ground_Break_Date__c,BOH_Install_Date__c = :BOH_Install_Date__c,Primary_BB_Install_Date__c = :Primary_BB_Install_Date__c,TTO_Install_Date__c = :TTO_Install_Date__c,Pre_Cable_Date__c = :Pre_Cable_Date__c,HME_Install_Date__c = :HME_Install_Date__c,Install_Date__c = :Install_Date__c,POS_Install_Date__c = :POS_Install_Date__c,Backup_BB_Install_Date__c = :Backup_BB_Install_Date__c,Telco_Install_Date__c = :Telco_Install_Date__c,Site_Survey_Date__c = :Site_Survey_Date__c,Opening_Support_Date__c = :Opening_Support_Date__c,Sea_Trial__c = :Sea_Trial__c,Mobile__c = :Mobile__c,OCB__c = :OCB__c,BOH__c = :BOH__c,KDS__c = :KDS__c,POS__c = :POS__c,HME__c = :HME__c,Airtight__c = :Airtight__c,LZ__c = :LZ__c,HZ__c = :HZ__c,Technology_Check_Last_Update__c = :Technology_Check_Last_Update__c,Verify_Store_is_in_EDM__c = :Verify_Store_is_in_EDM__c,Verify_AC_RGM_have_INIT_checklist__c = :Verify_AC_RGM_have_INIT_checklist__c,Verify_TACO_eRes_is_INIT__c = :Verify_TACO_eRes_is_INIT__c,Verify_no_issues_with_Tech__c = :Verify_no_issues_with_Tech__c,Verify_Store_Opened__c = :Verify_Store_Opened__c,Verify_store_shows_open_in_Remedy__c = :Verify_store_shows_open_in_Remedy__c,Verify_Gift_Cards_are_active__c = :Verify_Gift_Cards_are_active__c,Days_in_Implementation__c = :Days_in_Implementation__c,Days_in_Hypercare__c = :Days_in_Hypercare__c,Days_to_Stability__c = :Days_to_Stability__c,Verify_Store_can_access_LZ_HZ__c = :Verify_Store_can_access_LZ_HZ__c,Verify_Mobile_MIDs_sent_to_Tillster__c = :Verify_Mobile_MIDs_sent_to_Tillster__c,Verify_store_has_no_issues__c = :Verify_store_has_no_issues__c,Verify_Mobile_and_Gift_Card_setup_start__c = :Verify_Mobile_and_Gift_Card_setup_start__c WHERE Id = '$recordID'");
$stmt->bindParam(':Name', $updatedRecord->Name);
$stmt->bindParam(':Legal_Entity__c', $updatedRecord->Legal_Entity__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Opening_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Opening_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Owner_Type__c', $updatedRecord->Owner_Type__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':YumTracker_Status__c', $updatedRecord->YumTracker_Status__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Hypercare_Status__c', $updatedRecord->Hypercare_Status__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':BOH_Type__c', $updatedRecord->BOH_Type__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Store_Type__c', $updatedRecord->Store_Type__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Address_Line_1__c', $updatedRecord->Address_Line_1__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Address_Line_2__c', $updatedRecord->Address_Line_2__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':City__c', $updatedRecord->City__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':State__c', $updatedRecord->State__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Zip__c', $updatedRecord->Zip__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Store_Email_Address__c', $updatedRecord->Store_Email_Address__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Time_Zone__c', $updatedRecord->Time_Zone__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Area_Coach__c', $updatedRecord->Area_Coach__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':RGM__c', $updatedRecord->RGM__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':RTO_Date__c', $updatedRecord->RTO_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Ground_Break_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Ground_Break_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':BOH_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->BOH_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Primary_BB_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Primary_BB_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':TTO_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->TTO_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Pre_Cable_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Pre_Cable_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':HME_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->HME_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':POS_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->POS_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Backup_BB_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Backup_BB_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Telco_Install_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Telco_Install_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Site_Survey_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Site_Survey_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Opening_Support_Date__c', $updatedRecord->Opening_Support_Date__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Sea_Trial__c', $updatedRecord->Sea_Trial__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Mobile__c', $updatedRecord->Mobile__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':OCB__c', $updatedRecord->OCB__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':BOH__c', $updatedRecord->BOH__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':KDS__c', $updatedRecord->KDS__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':POS__c', $updatedRecord->POS__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':HME__c', $updatedRecord->HME__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Airtight__c', $updatedRecord->Airtight__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':LZ__c', $updatedRecord->LZ__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':HZ__c', $updatedRecord->HZ__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Technology_Check_Last_Update__c', $updatedRecord->Technology_Check_Last_Update__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Store_is_in_EDM__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Store_is_in_EDM__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_AC_RGM_have_INIT_checklist__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_AC_RGM_have_INIT_checklist__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_TACO_eRes_is_INIT__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_TACO_eRes_is_INIT__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_no_issues_with_Tech__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_no_issues_with_Tech__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Store_Opened__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Store_Opened__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_store_shows_open_in_Remedy__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_store_shows_open_in_Remedy__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Gift_Cards_are_active__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Gift_Cards_are_active__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Days_in_Implementation__c', $updatedRecord->Days_in_Implementation__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Days_in_Hypercare__c', $updatedRecord->Days_in_Hypercare__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Days_to_Stability__c', $updatedRecord->Days_to_Stability__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Store_can_access_LZ_HZ__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Store_can_access_LZ_HZ__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Mobile_MIDs_sent_to_Tillster__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Mobile_MIDs_sent_to_Tillster__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_store_has_no_issues__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_store_has_no_issues__c);
$stmt->bindParam(':Verify_Mobile_and_Gift_Card_setup_start__c', $updatedRecord->Verify_Mobile_and_Gift_Card_setup_start__c);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: `Not defined` sounds like a typo. You've searched all the names and placeholders and they match? Not your current issue but why not bind `$recordID`?

Comment: it seems a parameter in your object is not defined but to be sure you need to provide the object code please.

Comment: @chris85 It was an attempt to fix the problem before.  I compared the two sets of

Comment: I put the two sets of parameters and compared them in Excel, they are exactly the same.

Comment: The only difference I see is _Yum**t**racker_Status__c_ in the binds and _Yum**T**racker_Status__c_ in the SQL. Is your database engine picky on field name capitalization?